# how do i print list of numbers in sql and display them in column in ssrs just like as attandance sheet

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

This is the data:

[image]

And I want to make a report of monthly leave sheet like this:

[image]

Comment: use pivot table query for this

Comment: This seems to be a month and you want to place your data into a grid like a calendar? Don't paste pictures! Provide sample data and expected output. Please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If he has all the days and then the data as a simple table(Days with no data as null) then he can use the report wizard to do the pivoting in ssrs as opposed to sql.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
`ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by CompanyID) as LineNum`, 
`ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by EmployeeID) as LineNum` for each table respectively.

That should do it.

Alternatively you can also group this by Year, Month Date, and as your label, display the date.

Comment: Thankyou @a415 but it wouldn't work i tried this early